# What is the best practice for CSS-styled menu markup?

Tags: html, css, menu

So, I've been 'collecting' CSS menus for a while now (another term would be 'borrowing', yet another would be 'blatantly ripping off'), to learn from them and to potentially reuse some of the leetness in my own projects.

Being an oldschool HTML purist, I love the idea of styled `<ul>`s and `<ol>`s, and the better menus and tab interfaces tend to use this method, for accessibility or semantic soundness or whatever reason. I mainly like the method because it keeps my HTML source nice and clean.

Now, I've actually refactored my collection of CSS menus to fit one 'master' markup pattern that I've extrapolated from the most flexible examples out there, such as the CSS Zen Garden. It looks like this:

```
<div class="menustyle">
<ul>
    <li class="current"><a href="#" title="Page 1"><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Page 2"><span>Toys</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Page 3"><span>About Us</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Page 4"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<span class="clearit" /><br />
```

(the 'clearit' span at the end is used to set `clear:both` after menus that require it)

Anyway, I've seen variations on this markup on many sites, some with an extra enclosing `<div>`, some using a different word than `current`, some attaching the `current` class to the `<a>` tag rather than the `<li>`, and some leaving out the inner `<span>`. Everyone seems to have their own way of doing menu markup that's just a tiny bit different.

Anyway, after tinkering with a *lot* of menus, the above is what I've come up with, but I'm trying to figure out if there is an actual established best practice for this. I'd like to set up a simple CSS menu foundry at some point, and it would be nice to get some input on the markup before going any further.

**EDIT:** The question is **not** about Javascript menus. I *know* there are excellent scripted menus out there, and that they allow you to have submenus, more advanced animations and hover timing, shortcut keys, drop shadows, and everything else. But 90% of menus *don't need those features*, and are much better off using CSS for styling and hover effects.

Comment: And a bonus question for the Stack Overflow designers: why didn't you use the styled list method to make your tabs? I just took a swing at it, and they weren't too hard to replicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other than stripping out the span tags I think its fine.

There is no reason to have them becasue with your setup you can style the text however you want with

```
li a {/*styles*/}
```

You should also be able to remove the

```
<span class="clearit" /><br />
```

section as well.  If you're trying to float just the ul inside of the div you might as well scrap the div.  If you need the clear for some other reason you can do a

```
<br clear="all"/>
```

Comment: I've got a couple of menus where I was unable to strip away the spans (that's not to say it can't be done, of course). In certain cases you want the A tag to be as large as the LI (to allow clicking), but need a smaller span to position or style a smaller region inside. It gets tricky after that.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using span tags around specific subset of markup (although I prefer strong or em)... I said you could scrap them though because they were wrapping all of the anchor content.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `clearfix` class for UL (insdead of clearing span):

```
.clearfix:after {content:".";display:block;height:0;clear:both;visibility:hidden}
.clearfix {display:inline-block}
/* Hide from IE Mac \*/
.clearfix {display:block}
/* End hide from IE Mac */
* html .clearfix {height:1px}
```

Now, your menu will look like this:

```
<div class="menustyle">
<ul class="clearfix">
.....
```

Ofcourse, you can add those properties directly to UL to avoid any changes of html code :)

Answer (score 1):

CSS menus are a pain in the rear and so 2005.  All that cross-browser compatibility, IE javascript fix files and so on.  Specifically to answer your question: they're no different today than they were three years ago because IE7 doesn't support :hover on non-links and IE6 still needs to be supported.

These days just download jQuery, install the [Superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/) plug-in and include this code:

```
$(function() {
  $("ul.menu").superfish();
});
```

and done.  Even works on IE6 (with less features).

Comment: I think you're dead wrong here. I love jQuery, but most menus don't need the kind of extra bells and whistles that Superfish gives you. Plus, cross-browser CSS is really not as difficult as it was back in the days of IE5. Even Superfish uses CSS to achieve compatibility with IE6.

Comment: By the way, since I've been downvoted on this answer twice now: superfish actually gives working CSS menus with Javascript disabled (in Firefox at least; no menu will work in IE without Javascript as it doesn't support :hover on non-links).

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in having submenus then I'd recommend checking out the YUI library. It provides you with a cross browser compatible submenu from markup.

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/menu/index.html